# Huawei matebook d 14 ryzen 5 2500u

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, laptop, amd-processor, support

Hey is Huawei matebook d 14 ryzen 5 2500u running well on Ubuntu? Or any other Linux distribution?I couldn't find information online just that there are some problems with ryzen 5 2500u.

Comment: You could you try the [Huawei WMI Hotkeys Driver](https://github.com/aymanbagabas/Huawei-WMI) for the missing hotkeys. I have a MateBook X Pro.

Comment: This is not a duplicate as one is thinking about buying the laptop in order to use it with ubuntu, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

I just bought the Huawei Matebook D for university and I'm installing right now Ubuntu on a partition.
Everything works fine and there's no driver issues, the only thing that doesn't work is the mic hotkey, not a dealbreaker if you ask me!

Comment: can you please do some benchmarking of the GPU under linux and under Windows and see if it is similar? This benchmark seems to be availabel for both linux and windows https://benchmark.unigine.com/heaven

Comment: Did you not run into this issue? https://superuser.com/questions/1052023/ioapic0-not-in-ivrs-table

Comment: @Mehdi i'll try to do a benchmark run when I'll have the time, anyway I'm using it only for development purposes and it's running buttery smooth.

Comment: @KeatsKelleher nope, I didn't run into that problem.

Comment: Everything works fine. I just need to improve touchpad setting.

Answer (score 0):

The Ryzen CPU is not stable under Ubuntu. My system froze every few hours, and I could not find a fix. Upgrading the kernel to 4.19 did not help. Furthermore the Matebook ships with severely limited BIOS options, and I was not able to adjust some of the settings people with other Ryzen systems found to be relevant. I ended up returning the laptop after two weeks.

You can google "Ryzen freeze" for more threads on the subject, here is one example: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2394464

Comment: Question is about Huawei Matebook D not general Ryzen. There could be problems on other machines but our concern here is this particular model. I would appreciate answers from Matebook owners only.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I was a Matebook D owner when I wrote this answer, and I specifically mentioned this in my answer when I discussed the BIOS limitations on the Matebook D.